# clang-format not sorting main file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, llvm, clang-format

I have the following definition for my `.clang-format` file:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 0
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<'
    Priority:        -1
  - Regex:           '^"(gtest|gmock)/'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^"boost/'
    Priority:        2
  # Other rules ...
  - Regex:           '^"tools/'
    Priority:        14
  - Regex:           '^"[\w]+/'
    Priority:        15
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        16
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: true
SortIncludes: true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
...
```

The sorting of the header files works well, except for the file-to-main-include mapping. The main file is sorted by rule 16 and thus always appears at the end.

I have tried removing the sorting of the include files (i.e., commenting out parameters `IncludeBlocks` and `IncludeCategories`, but it still does not work. I thought that since the fallback style is LLVM, it would at least work in this case.

If I do not use my file, and instead specify `-style=llvm` in the command line, the sorting of the main file works.

I am using VS Code 1.45.1 on Debian 10, with extension [Clang-Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format) by `xaver`. The `clang-format` executable is version 10.0.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using .hpp for the header files? I don't think ClangFormat can detect anything except .h...

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `.clang-format` file is missing the `IncludeIsMainRegex` setting. Normally I would expect it to default to a reasonable setting, and everything would work fine. But given your problem, you should make sure it isn't set somewhere (perhaps you're using a different `.clang-format` file than you think you are? or perhaps your `clang-format` executable has somehow been modified?).

   The default setting is `IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'`. Other reasonable values might be `'([-_](test|unittest))?$'` (which matches what the predefined Google and Chromium styles use), `'$'` (meaning no additional filename suffix), or `''` (meaning any filename suffix). See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more information.
2. When your `Clang-Format` extension by `xaver` runs the `clang-format` executable, does it provide the filename on the command-line? Or does it, perhaps, stream the file into `stdin`? If the latter, then `clang-format` would not know the filename, and so would not be able to detect which include file is the "main" include file. One way that can be dealt with is by using the `-assume-filename` command-line option (documented [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)), but of course that is up to the extension to do.
3. Finally, remember that the "main" include file is sorted with priority `0`. Your setting for `IncludeCategories` has all include files that start with `<` sorted with priority `-1`, so they will be sorted *before* the "main" include file.